# Set file control value from model in asp.net mvc3 razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload, razor, model

In my MVC application, I am using following code for a file.

**MODEL**

```
public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
```

**VIEW**

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.File, new { type = "file" })
```

Everything working fine ..  for submitting value But I am trying to load file from controller model which is not working

CONTROLLER

```
public ActionResult ManagePhotos(ManagePhoto model)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
           //upload file
    }
    else
    {
          return View(model); //contains type HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
    }
}
```

how can i load file input again if my validation fails as after returning, my file control is not mapped to model to file and it's empty...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know that the file is valid, and want to keep it temporarily, you can keep it in session (but be aware of memory usage).

If you know the file is valid, and want to keep it permanently, save it and just keep the path in memory.

If you know that the file is invalid, you wont want to nor often be able to keep it.

Often this is treated in the same way during validation failure as a password - it needs to be provided again and as such is requested for only when everything else is good.

Comment: as i have several other files and i need to save all files at same submit. so i cannot save before all date is valid and i think session is not an option for me to store the file temporarily

do you have any other ideas about this..?

Comment: Well you either have to save them in server memory, or save them in server file storage or ask the client to reupload them every time. You could save them in the filesystem in a temp folder and then move from the temp folder to the permanent storage if the submit is a success.

Comment: for this i have an issue because if user does not perform `add operation` as well as user exits from application, it will be overhead to remove temp folder and i have limited storage over server.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to go as far as it takes to made user experience seamless, then try following:

1. Add javascript on the client side to validation the user inputs
2. On the server side temporarily store all the files on the tmp file storage. Clean up files older than 10 minutes. Do this when you need to save files into the storage